# LUbuntu installed "successfully" and now blank screen on boot?

Tags: lubuntu

So I originally had a stock install of Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my Asus EeePC900.

Due to Celeron 900 and Intel built in graphics, Unity was bogging the system down a bit. See related link here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/4dakhx/tailoring_a_default_install_of_1404_for_a_slow_cpu/

I decided to go with LUbuntu, which should speed things up a little bit.

I went through the entire install, all over again LUbuntu 16.04 and when it boots, I get a blank screen where I should have my login screen. I see signs of life, HDD Activity indicator blinking... But nothing else.

Is there any way to boot straight into text console?
Once I boot into text console, what do I do? 
Is there any way to boot into standard 640x480x16 colors standard VGA GUI?

I'm asuming this is a driver problem with the integrated Intel graphics. If this assumption is correct, how do I remedy it?

Answer (score 4):

The Intel graphics drivers are not installed by default, that's why it causes blank screen.

1. Hold <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> key during boot to access Grub menu, then press <kbd>e</kbd> key to edit commands.
2. Look for the words `quiet splash` on screen, use arrow keys to navigate and add `nomodeset` just after `quiet splash`(leave a space before and after nomodeset).
3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot into a low resolution desktop.
4. Now use Synaptic package manager(included in Lubuntu 16.04) to search and install `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and reboot.

**Edit:** You may need to enable `Restricted`, `Multiverse` and `Canonical Partners` options in Software & Updates to get access to the Intel drivers.

Comment: Why would the leave out arguably one of the most common graphics drivers?

Comment: Most likely to reduce size of disk image. Newer cards are catered for, just not the older 8xx & 9xx series...

Comment: How would I do this if I were using the live image on the USB flash drive? Try LUbuntu without installing also does the same thing.

Comment: On the menu screen where you see the option to `Try Lubuntu without installing` press `F6` to access `Other Options`. One of the options should be `nomodeset`.

Comment: F6 does nothing

Comment: If you using UNetbootin to create the USB boot flash, highlight the `Try Lubuntu without installing` option, press `Tab` key, add `nomodeset` just after `quiet splash` and press `Enter` key to continue.

Comment: I use Universal USB Installer 1.9.6.3 From PenDriveLinux.com I'll try UNetBoot and see what that does.

Comment: Loaded the flash with LUbuntu 16.04 i386 by way of UNetBootin... It booted once, but stayed at the LUbuntu screen with the flashing four dots. I hit F12 and saw a text screen... Login Service failed... I rebooted and now it won't do anything at the Blue menu. Even memory test or boot form first hard drive does nothing.

Comment: What filesystem is the USB flash drive you used? UNetbootin requires the flash drive to be formatted in FAT32 before usage.

Comment: It was FAT32. I had tried to install from it and botched the installs enough times, rebooting while the USB was busy, I think I corrupted it. I've got it now.

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted. Best of luck...

Answer (score 1):

Same for me. Researching, turns out lubuntu only installed basic system tools for lubuntu, leaving the black screen with HDD activity at top. Don't panic at this weird screen. Make sure internet is connected. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 in this screen will have you login with username and password. Then $ appears. Type all one line command at the blinking $ like this: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop && sudo shutdown -r now. Takes time to complete install. Tap spacebar at black screens to keep install progress "awake". The shutdown -r part in your command reboots it into gui automatically at end.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to

- press `esc` at reboot (instead of `right shift` key)
- select `... (recovery mode)` and `enter`
- select `root    Drop to root shell prompt` and `enter`
- add `nomodeset` at end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value in `/etc/default/grub`

  - `vi /etc/default/grub`
  - press `e`
  - Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
  - press `esc`
  - Type `:x` and `enter`
- regenerate new grub conf: `update-grub` on prompt and `enter`
- Type `reboot` on prompt and `enter`